# How to trim NULL address values in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table (fairly standard) which has the following columns

```
ADDRESS1
ADDRESS2
ADDRESS3
ADDRESS4
POSTCODE
```

I would like some T-SQL that I can apply to remove NULL values and shift the values up (I'd like to avoid cursors and loops where possible)

So if my data is

```
ID  ADDRESS1  ADDRESS2  ADDRESS3  ADDRESS4  POSTCODE
-----------------------------------------------------
1  50 The Street  NULL  The Town  The City  AB12 3GG
2  100 Avenue  Townsville  NULL  Metropolis  SG33 5WW
3  My House  NULL  NULL  FutureCity  KL21 6TT
```

it becomes

```
ID  ADDRESS1  ADDRESS2  ADDRESS3  ADDRESS4  POSTCODE
-----------------------------------------------------
1  50 The Street  The Town  The City  NULL  AB12 3GG
2  100 Avenue  Townsville  Metropolis  NULL  SG33 5WW
3  My House  FutureCity  NULL  NULL  KL21 6TT
```

(ie: all non NULL values are shifted left yet the postcode remains static)

Many thanks

Comment: I think you are going to have to use the CASE statement here... For those columns that you want to shift to the left OR right if they have null values...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by shifted. You are retrieving the columns right? Or are you concatenating everything into one stirng?

Comment: Are you wanting to change the permanent data in the table or just shift the data during a `SELECT`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever (and others) - sorry for not being clear - UPDATE the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution provided by "Low Chee Mun" is almost correct. It is correct if only one address is null, but you have call the update statement 3 times like below(for case if 3 addresses are null).

```
update T
set ADDRESS1 = (case when ADDRESS1 is null then ADDRESS2 else ADDRESS1 end),
ADDRESS2 = (case when ADDRESS1 is null or ADDRESS2 is null then ADDRESS3 else ADDRESS2 end),
ADDRESS3 = (case when ADDRESS1 is null or ADDRESS2 is null or ADDRESS3 is null then ADDRESS4 else ADDRESS3 end),
ADDRESS4 = (case when ADDRESS1 is null or ADDRESS2 is null or ADDRESS3 is null or ADDRESS4 is null then null else ADDRESS4 end)
from ADDR T;

update T
set ADDRESS1 = (case when ADDRESS1 is null then ADDRESS2 else ADDRESS1 end),
ADDRESS2 = (case when ADDRESS1 is null or ADDRESS2 is null then ADDRESS3 else ADDRESS2 end),
ADDRESS3 = (case when ADDRESS1 is null or ADDRESS2 is null or ADDRESS3 is null then ADDRESS4 else ADDRESS3 end),
ADDRESS4 = (case when ADDRESS1 is null or ADDRESS2 is null or ADDRESS3 is null or ADDRESS4 is null then null else ADDRESS4 end)
from ADDR T;

update T
set ADDRESS1 = (case when ADDRESS1 is null then ADDRESS2 else ADDRESS1 end),
ADDRESS2 = (case when ADDRESS1 is null or ADDRESS2 is null then ADDRESS3 else ADDRESS2 end),
ADDRESS3 = (case when ADDRESS1 is null or ADDRESS2 is null or ADDRESS3 is null then ADDRESS4 else ADDRESS3 end),
ADDRESS4 = (case when ADDRESS1 is null or ADDRESS2 is null or ADDRESS3 is null or ADDRESS4 is null then null else ADDRESS4 end)
from ADDR T;
```

Comment: cool, my answer is just for references, steady, you can make 3 update statement in one query also xD

Answer (score 1):

I think you need three update statements to shift from each column.

```
UPDATE YourTable  
SET ADDRESS1 = ADDRESS2,
    ADDRESS2 = ADDRESS3,
    ADDRESS3 = ADDRESS4,
    ADDRESS4 = NULL
WHERE ADDRESS1 IS NULL

GO

UPDATE YourTable  
SET ADDRESS2 = ADDRESS3,
    ADDRESS3 = ADDRESS4,
    ADDRESS4 = NULL
WHERE ADDRESS2 IS NULL

GO


UPDATE YourTable  
SET ADDRESS3 = ADDRESS4,
    ADDRESS4 = NULL
WHERE ADDRESS3 IS NULL

GO
```

Comment: Thanks @Kiran - I think I'll go with this approach and amend to cope with consecutive NULL columns

Answer (score 1):

no problem, no loop or cursor is required,

use update from and every time check against value itself or above level

sample :  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba1cb/3